# Disable overlay links when not active (mobile device)

Tags: css, overlay

First of all, please be indulgent. I am very noob with CSS but I have some base.

So my problem is with this mobile device version of my [website](http://lescurateurs.ca)

For desktop, it’s not a problem if the image is hovered the overlay is shown and you can click on the link.

The mobile devices, on the other hand, is more problematic. What I want is that a tap on the image shows the overlay and the second tap can click on the link. This worked fine as long as you don’t tap on the link area.

What could I do?

I tried pointer-events but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that with javascript (I used jQuery here) :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     /**
     * Detect if the device is a touch device (tablet, mobile, ...)
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function isTouchDevice() {
        return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
    }
    
    // Get the previous element clicked (if there is multiple items with the same class
    let previousClick = null;
    $('.box').on('click', function (e) {
        if (isTouchDevice()) {
          e.preventDefault(); // Don't go to the link if it's a               touch device
          if (this === previousClick) {
            window.location.replace($(this).attr('href'));
          }
          previousClick = this;
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.box_container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.box {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.box p {
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.box:hover p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_container">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="box">
      <p>My super Overlay</p>
    </a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```